# Show legend item into two column

Tags: wpf, data-visualization, wpftoolkit

I am using WpfToolkit to draw a Pie chart,and I like to show my legend into two column due to my legend is to much,how can I solve it?

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart Height="auto" x:Name="PieChart2" Title="{Binding}"  
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="5" LegendTitle="Label" >
            <chartingToolkit:PieSeries DependentValuePath="Value"
        IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            </chartingToolkit:PieSeries>
            <charting:Chart.LegendStyle>
                <Style TargetType="datavis:Legend">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </charting:Chart.LegendStyle>
        </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: but why there's a need for two columns when there is default scrollviewer  provided in the legend

Comment: @VishalPrajapati sorry for making u confuse, I need to print the data into pdf and the function is not allow the scrollviewer which is provided, so I have to show all the legend out without showing the scrollviewer.

Answer (score 0):

As per your need , I have changed the ControlTemplate of the Legend a litte as shown below

```
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="LegendControlTemplate1"
                     TargetType="{x:Type visualizationToolkit:Legend}">
        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                Padding="2">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <visualizationToolkit:Title x:Name="HeaderContent"
                                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                            Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                            Grid.Row="0"
                                            Style="{TemplateBinding TitleStyle}" />
                <ScrollViewer BorderThickness="0"
                              IsTabStop="False"
                              Padding="0"
                              Grid.Row="1"
                              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <!--<ItemsPresenter  x:Name="Items"
                                    Margin="10,0,10,10" >
                    </ItemsPresenter>-->
                    <ItemsControl x:Name="Items"
                                  Margin="10,0,10,10"
                                  ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <UniformGrid Columns="2" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    </ItemsControl>

                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

I am not sure whether this suites your requirement or not..Please mark it as answer if satisfied.